# How do I create a table where it specifies which cell it starts iterating in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a calendar where the user enters a number (1-12) for the month and (1-7; where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday)for the day. for example, I enter 1 for month and 5 for day. so the output would be a January calendar and has the 1st day of the month starting at Thursday. I got the month function working already however I am having trouble doing the 2nd one where the user enters the number (1-7) and starts iterating from 1-31 from there. so far, this is what I have so far

here is my table

```
        <TABLE BORDER=3 CELLSPACING=3 CELLPADDING=3 class="center">
                <TR>
               <TD COLSPAN="7" ALIGN=center id="monthlbl"><B></B></TD>
               </TR>
        
               <TR>
               <TD ALIGN=center>Sun</TD>
               <TD ALIGN=center>Mon</TD>
               <TD ALIGN=center>Tue</TD>
               <TD ALIGN=center>Wed</TD>
               <TD ALIGN=center>Thu</TD>
               <TD ALIGN=center>Fri</TD>
               <TD ALIGN=center>Sat</TD>
               </TR>
  
               </TABLE>
```

so far the script I have for the 2nd function is

```
        <script>
         if (document.getElementById("daytxt").value = "1" ){
          "traverse through table with starting day as sunday and create more rows as program traverses from 1-31"
         }
         </script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but nothing what you wrote makes any sense.

Comment: hello, i added some more details to my question